# Remove undefined from a string

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to do, binary search using Javascript, everything is working fine, but I'm unable to console(display) the undefined value(I want to print 'the number is not in the list' if the item is not in the list.)

Thanks in advance.

Here is my code:

```
function bSearch(userInput, numb){
//var inputSplit = userInput.toString().split('');
var input = numSort(userInput);
//console.log(input);
var start = 0;

var n = input.length;
//console.log(n);
var end = n-1;
var output = '';
//var mid = (start + end) / 2;
// console.log(mid);
while(start <= end){
var mid = (start + end) / 2;
mid = Math.floor(mid);
//console.log(mid);
if(input[mid] == numb){
    output = input[mid];
    return output;      
}else if(numb < input[mid]){
    end = mid - 1;
}else if(numb > input[mid]){
    start = mid + 1;
}
```

}
}

```
function numSort(num){
var temp = '';
var res = '';
arr = num.toString().split('');
var n = arr.length; 
for(i=0; i<n-1; i++){
    for(d=0; d<n-i-1; d++){
        if(arr[d] > arr[d+1]){
            temp = arr[d];
            arr[d] = arr[d+1];
            arr[d+1] = temp;                
        }
}

}
for(i=0; i<n; i++){
    res += arr[i];
}return res;
```

}

Comment: please add some inputs and expected outputs.

Comment: Sure. here is my input: if console.log(bSearch(245198, 2)); It is displaying 2. but if console.log(bSearch(245198, 3)); it shows 'undefined'

Answer (score 1):

Add the return statement at the end of the function

```
function bSearch(userInput, numb) {
    // lots of code (some vars without declarations ...)
    // ...
    return 'the number is not in the list';
}
```

This is preventing `undefined`. Instead it is returning the string.